# How can I push an element to the bottom of a div in tailwind? Should be simple, but just can't get it to work

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a layout in tailwind which is pretty typical: a number of 'cards' which are placed into a grid container. Each card has a photo and some other text details with a button at the bottom of the card.

All I want to do is push the button to the bottom of the card. The code is below and there is also a link to play.tailwind.

```
<div class="grid sm:block grid-cols-5 sm:grid-cols-1 col-span-12 sm:col-span-6 md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3 p-4">
  <div class="flex sm:h-[17em] mr-4 sm:mr-0 sm:mb-4 col-span-2 sm:col-span-1">
    <img class="grow object-cover" :src=''>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col col-span-3 sm:col-span-1">
    <p class="mb-3">
      text
    </p>
    <p class="mb-3">
      more text
    </p>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-1 mb-3">
      some more text
    </div>
    <p class="mb-4 flex-1">
      even more
    </p>
    <button>
      the problem button
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[play.tailwind example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/SnOJFe3dmn)

To me, it seems like `<p class="mb-4 flex-1">` should take care of everything. But maybe it can't because its container won't allow it to grow? If I try to assign a `h-full` to its container, it extends past the card's container which is unexpected.

I've done this sort of thing before without thinking much about it. When I first encountered this problem, I went back and rebuilt the entire structure. After looking through the official docs and trying a number of methods using grids and flex, I'm even more confused. I just can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the `<div class="flex flex-col col-span-3 sm:col-span-1">` element is only as high as its content. This means there is no empty space for the `flex-grow: 1` part of `flex-1` to grow into:

[image: Parent height does not take up the full height of the available empty space]

Consider adjusting the CSS so this element extends to the bottom of the content box of its own parent. Consider the following few methods of many:

#### Grid

Have the parent stay as a grid layout beyond the `sm:` breakpoint. Have two explicit grid row tracks, one that is the height of the image and another that is `1fr` to fill the remaining vertical space. This then lets the aforementioned `<div>` expand fully, thus letting the `<p>` element expand fully:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="bg-slate-400 py-24">
  <div class="container mx-auto grid grid-cols-12 gap-8 px-4">
    <div class="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-5 border p-4 sm:col-span-6 sm:grid-cols-1 sm:grid-rows-[max-content_1fr] md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3">
      <div class="col-span-2 mr-4 flex sm:col-span-1 sm:mb-4 sm:mr-0 sm:h-[17em]">
        <img class="grow border object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 flex flex-col sm:col-span-1">
        <p class="mb-3 font-serif text-2xl">First Last</p>
        <p class="mb-3 text-sm font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">City, Country</p>
        <div class="-mx-1 mb-3 flex flex-wrap text-xs font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">
          <div class="m-1 inline w-min break-words rounded bg-slate-800 px-3 py-1 text-slate-400">Something</div>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-4 flex-1">Bio text here: Fusce in lacus lobortis, luctus eros nec, maximus nisl.</p>
        <button class="border">The problem</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-5 border p-4 sm:col-span-6 sm:grid-cols-1 sm:grid-rows-[max-content_1fr] md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3">
      <div class="col-span-2 mr-4 flex sm:col-span-1 sm:mb-4 sm:mr-0 sm:h-[17em]">
        <img class="grow border object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 flex flex-col sm:col-span-1">
        <p class="mb-3 font-serif text-2xl">First Last</p>
        <p class="mb-3 text-sm font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">City, Country</p>
        <div class="-mx-1 mb-3 flex flex-wrap text-xs font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">
          <div class="m-1 inline w-min break-words rounded bg-slate-800 px-3 py-1 text-slate-400">Something</div>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-4 flex-1">Bio text here: Nam non lorem ac ex hendrerit semper.</p>
        <button class="border">Also the problem</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-5 border p-4 sm:col-span-6 sm:grid-cols-1 sm:grid-rows-[max-content_1fr] md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3">
      <div class="col-span-2 mr-4 flex sm:col-span-1 sm:mb-4 sm:mr-0 sm:h-[17em]">
        <img class="grow border object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 flex flex-col sm:col-span-1">
        <p class="mb-3 font-serif text-2xl">First Last</p>
        <p class="mb-3 text-sm font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">City, Country</p>
        <div class="-mx-1 mb-3 flex flex-wrap text-xs font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">
          <div class="m-1 inline w-min break-words rounded bg-slate-800 px-3 py-1 text-slate-400">Something</div>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-4 flex-1">Bio text here: Morbi egestas massa vel nunc scelerisque viverra. Aliquam a urna vel quam rhoncus laoreet. Cras volutpat velit sed arcu varius iaculis. Nam cursus eros in porttitor dictum.</p>
        <button class="border">A button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Vertical Flex

Have the parent as a vertical flex layout beyond the `sm:` breakpoint. Have the `<div>` expand fully by applying `flex-grow: 1` via the `grow` class, thus letting the `<p>` element expand fully:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="bg-slate-400 py-24">
  <div class="container mx-auto grid grid-cols-12 gap-8 px-4">
    <div class="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-5 border p-4 sm:col-span-6 sm:flex sm:flex-col md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3">
      <div class="col-span-2 mr-4 flex sm:col-span-1 sm:mb-4 sm:mr-0 sm:h-[17em]">
        <img class="grow border object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 flex grow flex-col sm:col-span-1">
        <p class="mb-3 font-serif text-2xl">First Last</p>
        <p class="mb-3 text-sm font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">City, Country</p>
        <div class="-mx-1 mb-3 flex flex-wrap text-xs font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">
          <div class="m-1 inline w-min break-words rounded bg-slate-800 px-3 py-1 text-slate-400">Something</div>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-4 flex-1">Bio text here: Fusce in lacus lobortis, luctus eros nec, maximus nisl.</p>
        <button class="border">The problem</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-5 border p-4 sm:col-span-6 sm:flex sm:flex-col md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3">
      <div class="col-span-2 mr-4 flex sm:col-span-1 sm:mb-4 sm:mr-0 sm:h-[17em]">
        <img class="grow border object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 flex grow flex-col sm:col-span-1">
        <p class="mb-3 font-serif text-2xl">First Last</p>
        <p class="mb-3 text-sm font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">City, Country</p>
        <div class="-mx-1 mb-3 flex flex-wrap text-xs font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">
          <div class="m-1 inline w-min break-words rounded bg-slate-800 px-3 py-1 text-slate-400">Something</div>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-4 flex-1">Bio text here: Nam non lorem ac ex hendrerit semper.</p>
        <button class="border">Also the problem</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-5 border p-4 sm:col-span-6 sm:flex sm:flex-col md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3">
      <div class="col-span-2 mr-4 flex sm:col-span-1 sm:mb-4 sm:mr-0 sm:h-[17em]">
        <img class="grow border object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 flex grow flex-col sm:col-span-1">
        <p class="mb-3 font-serif text-2xl">First Last</p>
        <p class="mb-3 text-sm font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">City, Country</p>
        <div class="-mx-1 mb-3 flex flex-wrap text-xs font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">
          <div class="m-1 inline w-min break-words rounded bg-slate-800 px-3 py-1 text-slate-400">Something</div>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-4 flex-1">Bio text here: Morbi egestas massa vel nunc scelerisque viverra. Aliquam a urna vel quam rhoncus laoreet. Cras volutpat velit sed arcu varius iaculis. Nam cursus eros in porttitor dictum.</p>
        <button class="border">A button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Height Calculation

Have the `<div>` fill the remaining space of its parent by setting its `height` appropriately. We wouldn't apply `height: 100%` (`h-full`) as you have found out, it would overflow. This is because the height would be the height of the container, but we have other elements alongside – the `<img>` container. What we can do instead is since the `<img>` container has a set height, we can calculate the `height` that the `<div>` should be as follows:

```
height = 100% - [Height of image container] - [Vertical margin of image container]
       = 100% - 17em - theme(spacing.5)
```

```css
height: calc(100% - 17em - theme(spacing.5))
```

```html
<div class="… h-[calc(100%-17em-theme(spacing.5))]">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="bg-slate-400 py-24">
  <div class="container mx-auto grid grid-cols-12 gap-8 px-4">
    <div class="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-5 border p-4 sm:col-span-6 sm:block md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3">
      <div class="col-span-2 mr-4 flex sm:col-span-1 sm:mb-4 sm:mr-0 sm:h-[17em]">
        <img class="grow border object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 flex flex-col sm:col-span-1 sm:h-[calc(100%-17em-theme(spacing.4))]">
        <p class="mb-3 font-serif text-2xl">First Last</p>
        <p class="mb-3 text-sm font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">City, Country</p>
        <div class="-mx-1 mb-3 flex flex-wrap text-xs font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">
          <div class="m-1 inline w-min break-words rounded bg-slate-800 px-3 py-1 text-slate-400">Something</div>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-4 flex-1">Bio text here: Fusce in lacus lobortis, luctus eros nec, maximus nisl.</p>
        <button class="border">The problem</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-5 border p-4 sm:col-span-6 sm:block md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3">
      <div class="col-span-2 mr-4 flex sm:col-span-1 sm:mb-4 sm:mr-0 sm:h-[17em]">
        <img class="grow border object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 flex flex-col sm:col-span-1 sm:h-[calc(100%-17em-theme(spacing.4))]">
        <p class="mb-3 font-serif text-2xl">First Last</p>
        <p class="mb-3 text-sm font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">City, Country</p>
        <div class="-mx-1 mb-3 flex flex-wrap text-xs font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">
          <div class="m-1 inline w-min break-words rounded bg-slate-800 px-3 py-1 text-slate-400">Something</div>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-4 flex-1">Bio text here: Nam non lorem ac ex hendrerit semper.</p>
        <button class="border">Also the problem</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-12 grid grid-cols-5 border p-4 sm:col-span-6 sm:block md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-3">
      <div class="col-span-2 mr-4 flex sm:col-span-1 sm:mb-4 sm:mr-0 sm:h-[17em]">
        <img class="grow border object-cover" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-3 flex flex-col sm:col-span-1 sm:h-[calc(100%-17em-theme(spacing.4))]">
        <p class="mb-3 font-serif text-2xl">First Last</p>
        <p class="mb-3 text-sm font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">City, Country</p>
        <div class="-mx-1 mb-3 flex flex-wrap text-xs font-medium uppercase tracking-widest">
          <div class="m-1 inline w-min break-words rounded bg-slate-800 px-3 py-1 text-slate-400">Something</div>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-4 flex-1">Bio text here: Morbi egestas massa vel nunc scelerisque viverra. Aliquam a urna vel quam rhoncus laoreet. Cras volutpat velit sed arcu varius iaculis. Nam cursus eros in porttitor dictum.</p>
        <button class="border">A button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Wongjn. Very comprehensive and clear. I ended up using the flex method and everything works great. Also, `grid-rows-[max-content_1fr]` is very interesting; I would have never thought of that—I'll try make use of it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I typically choose part of the card I want to expand and use `flex-grow`. I've given a basic example of a "card" below.

```html
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div>
      <h2>The title of the card</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-grow">
      <!-- This will grow vertically -->
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">More information</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've put an example here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/WuOJpFvXc6

Comment: They already have `flex-grow: 1` applied to the part of the card they want to expand. `flex-1` applies `flex-grow: 1` via `flex: 1 1 0%`. The issue is that the container of that portion of the card itself is not expanding into the extra vertical space.